# Using nth-child or nth-of-type I want to select this pattern -1,5,9,13,17,19..-

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-position

I have 4 cards on each row under a parent element and I want to apply certain styles on every 2nd element of the row using nth-child or nth-of-type

> 0_**1**_2_3
>
> 4_**5**_6_7
>
> 8_**9**_10_11
>
> 12_**13**_14_15

Answer (score 4):

This should do it.

```css
li:nth-child(4n + 2)
```

- `4n` is just an expression you plug numbers into: `4(1) = 4th element`, `4(2) = 8th element`, etc.
- `+ 2` is a constant which starts the query from the second child element.

```css
li:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

li { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 0</li>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
  <li>item 9</li>
  <li>item 10</li>
  <li>item 11</li>
  <li>item 12</li>
  <li>item 13</li>
  <li>item 14</li>
  <li>item 15</li>
</ul>
```